# Can't find .profile file in OS X

Tags: macos, .profile

I'm trying to install TBB (Thread Building Blocks) from Intel onto my Mac. However, no matter where I look, I can't find the `.profile` file that I require to modify to use TBB.

Any advice or hints on where I could find it?

If it's hidden, how can I unhide it? (I'm new to OS X)

I have read some articles that say I could make my own `.profile` file but I don't think it's what I need to install the TBB.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is no `~/.profile` by default.

Some background: when you start your Terminal.app, it loads a shell – in your case Bash. Shells can have configuration files, and `.profile` is one of these. They are read when the shell starts up, in a specific order. You can run `man bash` and read the section "Invocation" for more details.

Now, under macOS, I would recommend to not create a `.profile` file, but a `.bash_profile` file instead. For Bash, this will make no difference in functionality. Note however that once you create a file called `~/.bash_profile`, your `~/.profile` will not be read anymore, and since most guides will want you to modify `.bash_profile`, it's better to stick to this one.

You can simply create the file if it doesn't exist and open it in a text editor.

```
touch ~/.bash_profile
open -e !$
```

Save it, and the next time you start a new instance of Bash (e.g. by opening a new Terminal window), your `~/.bash_profile` will be read and all commands therein will be executed.

Comment: I tried this but got a syntax error message, with a pointer at the "~", any suggestions?

Comment: @StuartJeckel What error exactly? There shouldn't be a problem with this.. are you sure you've copy-pasted exactly as shown?

Comment: The .bash_profile note is very important here

Comment: @chrismarx You're right, I actually rewrote the answer to tell users to just go ahead and create a `.bash_profile` instead of a `.profile`.

Comment: @slhck thanks! I set my $NPM_TOKEN in this bash file but `echo $NPM_TOKEN` shows nothing still. (trying to permanently set it system wide)

Comment: @BenRacicot Your `.bash_profile` is not automatically read system-wide, only when you actually start Bash through your terminal. It depends on your operating system and what other files you have. Perhaps you should ask a new question and give us some more details (and maybe try putting `echo` statements in the files to see which are being loaded).